# How to add image and text into PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to create a large image CTA for my new WordPress site. I have created a new field group and made the type "group" on ACF. I have put functions into phpstorm but none of my images, text or link are showing. I am assuming I made a mistake in the function, it was copied from the ACF site

Tried adding loop functions with have_rows() functions as well as changing the ACF type to repeater. Nothing is working and I have no clue how to solve this. Please help

```
 <?php if( have_rows('large_cta') ):

     while( have_rows('large_cta') ): the_row();

         // vars
         $image = get_sub_field('large_image');
         $link = get_sub_field('large_link');

         ?>
         <div id="hero">
             <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
             <div class="content">
                 <?php the_sub_field('large_title'); ?>
                 <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $link['title']; ?></a>
             </div>
         </div>
         <style type="text/css">
             #hero {
                 background: <?php the_sub_field('color'); ?>;
             }
         </style>
     <?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Shows no results. I have attached an image of what the final design is supposed to look like. [final design img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AGo7.png)

Comment: Are your fields named the same way in the backend?

Comment: yes they are. I am not sure if this is the right function to create the groups/blocks like in the final design though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and done some changes in ACF fields & code.

[image: change in acf fields for repeater]

You can try below code in your template

```
if (have_rows('large_cta')):
    while (have_rows('large_cta')): the_row();

        // vars
        $image = get_sub_field('large_image');
        $link = get_sub_field('large_link');
        $color = get_sub_field('color');
        ?>
        <div id="hero" style="<?php if ($image) { ?> background:url('<?php echo $image; ?>') center center no-repeat;<?php } else { ?>background: <?php echo $color; ?>;<?php } ?>">
            <div class="content">
                <h2><?php the_sub_field('large_heading'); ?></h2>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('large_title'); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>"><?php echo $link['title']; ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style type="text/css">
            #hero {
                width: 100%;
                height:500px;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
            }
            .content {
                text-align: center;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                color: #fff;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            .content h2 {
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .content p {
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .content a {
                background: #00BCD4;
                padding: 10px 30px;
                border-radius: 3px;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: capitalize;
                color: #fff;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    endwhile; 
 endif;
```

[image: final output]